# Oracle - generating XML that contains multibyte characters, LPX-00216 error

Tags: xml, oracle, multibyte

Database (11g) charset is US7ASCII and I'm trying to build some XML with UTF-8 encoding.

I'm using convert to handle (or so I'm thinking) the US7ASCII to UTF8 part.

Sample code:

```
declare
v_text2 varchar2(100);
v_text2_conv varchar2(100);
v_xml varchar2(1000);
begin
select building_name into v_text2 from adam_source; -- grab some multibyte data
select convert(trim(v_text2),'UTF8','US7ASCII') into v_text2_conv from dual; -- convert to UTF8
select xmlroot(xmlelement("test2",XMLCDATA(v_text2_conv)),version '1.0" encoding="UTF-    8').getclobval() into v_xml from dual; -- Build XML
dbms_output.put_line(v_xml); -- Display XML
end;
/
```

I get the error:

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00216: invalid character 239 (0xEF)
```

Any pointers MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
PRG3 SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.1.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production

PRG3 SQL> select convert(building_name,'UTF8','US7ASCII') from adam_source;

CONVERT(BUILDING_NAME,'UTF8','US7ASCII')
--------------------------------------------------
�������r��



PRG3 SQL> select convert('12345','UTF8','US7ASCII') from dual;

CONVE
-----
12345
```

..first one is some double-byte field, second one is a simple conversion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I generated some sample data:

```
PRG3 SQL> create table adam_test (test char(50));

Table created.

PRG3 SQL> insert into adam_test (select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(hextoraw('819B819B92AC8372838B20202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020')) from dual);

1 row created.

PRG3 SQL> select * from adam_test;

TEST
--------------------------------------------------
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒r▒▒
```